# How to check if a Folder exists in Computer desktop from C#?

Tags: c#

I need to check weather a Folder exists in desktop of computer from C# `C:\\Users\\MyComputer\\Desktop\\Test`.  If not exist I need to add a folder `Test`.

I have code to create a folder `Test`

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(desktopPath + "\\Test");
```

But before that I need to check if that folder is exist or not. How to check from C# ? Help me to complete this task.

Thanks in advance.
Srihari

Comment: `System.IO.Directory.Exists("path")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for

[Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Test"))
{
     //directory doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with this

> ```
> System.IO.Directory.Exists(desktopPath + "\\Test");
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
if(!Directory.Exists(desktopPath + "\\Test")
{
   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(desktopPath + "\\Test");
}
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `Directory.Exists()` Method found in `System.IO` [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Its fairly simple:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
bool exists = Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(desktopPath, "FolderName"))

if (!exists)
{
  //FOLDER DOESN'T EXIST...
}
```